#  Printing PDFs to file but name of file saves with weird box-symbol  with F022 inside

Tags: pdf

When I print a website to PDF, the file name saves with a weird box-symbol  with  **F022** inside. Anyone know why? I'm new to Ubuntu, and not sure if this is a problem with my system, maybe I installed something wrong, not sure....

After Googling, I found it toward the middle of this webpage:

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f022/index.htm

The following is from the website:

string.toUpperCase()    
string.toLowerCase()    

Someone else posted a similar issue 2years ago on this tread: 
[Text inside files has squares with numbers in it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47328/text-inside-files-has-squares-with-numbers-in-it/447735#447735) but they were getting it due to OCR it sounds like. 
In anycase HP M......

Answer (score 0):

That symbol represent no other thing but a unicode character. Basically, it displays that kind of characters (the ones with hexadecimal numbers inside a square) when the particular character is not supported by the font you're currently using.

You can check, if you've got a font which is able to display it, in the following link: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f022/browsertest.htm

And here they are the fonts which support that character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/f022/fontsupport.htm

I doesn't look like is a particular issue of your system or of your installation. I neither can to display that character.

Greetings.